# Is there a Tezos equivalent of ERC?

Tags: smart-contracts

I’d like to read / contribute to existing contract standards on Tezos, is there an open source movement like ERC?

Answer (score 7):

Martin Pospěch drafted an Tezos "ICO token" standard at https://gitlab.com/tips2/TIPs/blob/master/TIPS/tip-7.md

Stephen Andrews is working on a tztoken at http://tztoken.teztech.io/

OcamlPro has a token contact (in Liquidity) in its examples available at http://www.liquidity-lang.org/edit/. You can also see code for that at https://github.com/OCamlPro/liquidity/blob/next/tests/others/token.liq

Comment: your link to https://stephenandrews.github.io/tztoken/ is giving a 404

Comment: I just fixed that to reference the new tztoken address.

Answer (score 2):

There are currently two standards (I've included permalinks in case things change).

- [FA1.2](https://gitlab.com/tzip/tzip/-/blob/369bbed94a1f0fe710ca625d3dec9d46b295e460/proposals/tzip-7/tzip-7.md) is a simple ERC20 like contract for fungible assets. It does not define a metadata protocol for things like symbol, name or decimals.
- [FA2](https://gitlab.com/tzip/tzip/-/blob/369bbed94a1f0fe710ca625d3dec9d46b295e460/proposals/tzip-12/tzip-12.md) is a multi asset contract. It can hold a single or multiple fungible and non-fungible tokens in a single contract. It also supports custom approval schemas and extensive metadata options.

Answer (score 1):

The Tezos equivalent of Ethereum's EIP (and ERC) is called TZIP. The TZIP repository is  https://gitlab.com/tzip/tzip/. The TZIPs can also be browsed on https://tzip.tezosagora.org/ and the proposals can be discussed on [the Tezos Agora forum](https://forum.tezosagora.org/c/tzip/16).